# Update an element created via appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I created a table on my document using: `document.body.appendChild(table)`

now every time I make a change on my table I want to run

```
document.body.removeChild(table)
document.body.appendChild(table)
```

so that the content of the table on my page is updated. This does however not work in the first place as I get

> app.js:75 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

as an error message, and it also seems like a really clunky solution to the problem.

Comment: But first perform a minimum of research https://www.google.nl/search?q=dom+update+html+table

Comment: I know I tried but I'm fairly new so I dont always find the correct key terms :)

Answer (score 1):

> now every time I make a change on my table I want to run...so that the content of the table on my page is updated

There's no need to do that. Just modify the table. It's an object in the DOM; modifications to it are rendered by the browser. This is fundamental to how the DOM works.

```js
var table = document.createElement("table");
var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
table.appendChild(tbody);
document.body.appendChild(table);
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // This modifies the existing table
    tbody.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        "<tr><td>" + tbody.children.length + "</td></tr>"
    );
    if (tbody.children.length == 5) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your appended table is returned by `appendChild`. You can use it to modify in future.